# Should I use AsyncTask class inside the MainActivity extending Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was wondering if `AsyncTask` was made to be used inside the main activity (`MainActivity.java`) running the thread.

For example I noticed many tutorials when using the `AsyncTask` they declare a private class inside the main class extending the `Activity` rather than creating an independent `.java` file for that `AsyncTask` (`MyAsyncTask.java`) `class`.

But I noticed that when using an independent file i'm not being able to run the `runOnUIThread`() because it belongs to the `Activity` class, so how will i be able to use this method inside that independent `AsyncTask` (MyAsyncTask.java) which extends `AsyncTask` and not `Activity`.

Comment: why would you want to call runOnUIThread from AsyncTask?

Comment: to change TextViews, they cannot be changed from other threads.

Comment: You can update the UI in onPostExecute and onPreExecute

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can update your textview by the way i have written in code.May that help you!

Comment: Use onPreExecute() , onProgressUpdate(), and onPostExecute() for using Activity methods. onProgressUpdate() is used for notifiying progress. Depends on you. [Best AsyncTask tutorial](https://androidride.com/asynctask-android-tutorial-example/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is completely fine. I do it often but it depends on how you are using it. If it may be used by othe `Activities` then I give it it's own class or a shared class. But if it is for a single purpose then I would make it an inner class of the `MainActivity`.

The benefit of making it an inner class is that it has direct access to that classes member variables. If you make it a separate class then you just need to create a constructor for it if you need to pass in `params` such as a `context` or other variables.

I don't know exactly what you are doing but I'm not sure you need `runOnUiThread()`. You can create a constructor in your `AsyncTask` file and have it accept `context` as a param and whatever else you need. Then you can update the `UI` in `onPostExecute()`

**Example**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

    private Context context; 

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {  // can take other params if needed
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Add your AsyncTask methods and logic
    //you can use your context variable in onPostExecute() to manipulate activity UI
}
```

then call it in your `MainActivity`

```
MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);  //can pass other variables as needed
myTask.execute();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i like it, the problem is that runOnUIThread() cannot be ran if it's an independent file, I will have to use it an inner class, which I don't want because i'm gonna use the same class for 3 activities, and i'm not gonna put the whole piece of code of AsyncTask in every activity

Comment: You don't have to use an inner class. Pass a reference to the activity as a parameter in the constructor (like what codeMagic is describing). Then use the reference to the activity to call the runOnUIThread() method

Comment: I added a small example if you need it. Ok, good, I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: oups sorry!! that was by mistake!! :D

Answer (score 9):

Generally, we place `AsyncTask` in the same class to make it more clear that it is used by the same activity only.

If you want that `AsyncTask` to be reused by more than one activity than, you can simply create an independent class and pass the parameters from the activity by constructors

You can create an interface in your AsyncTask to send a response from AsyncTask to your activity like below and call your listener method whenever required. I have called it `onPostExecute()`:

```
public class DeckDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    OnDownloadUpdateListener listener;
    
    public interface OnDownloadUpdateListener {
         public void OnDownloadDeckFinish(String Response);     
    }


    public DeckDownloader(Context ctx, OnDownloadUpdateListener listener) {
         mContext = ctx;
         this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
         String str = "downloading";
         //your async code goes here
         return str;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          if( listener != null ) {
                listener.OnDownloadDeckProgress(result);
          }
     }
}
```

And in Your Activity class, you need to implement that listener and write your code to update textview in that implementation method:

```
    public class myActivity extends Activity{
          private DeckDownloader.OnDownloadUpdateListener downloadListener;
          TextView txtAsyncResponse;

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              txtAsyncResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAsyncResponse);
    

            downloadListener = new DeckDownloader.OnDownloadUpdateListener() {
               @Override
               public void OnDownloadDeckFinish(String Response) {
                    txtAsyncResponse.setText(Response);
               }
            };
    }
```

And you can write the below code to start AsyncTask in your activity whenever required like button click event or else

```
 DeckDownloader mTask = new DeckDownloader(this.getApplicationContext(), downloadListener);
 mTask.execute();
```

This can be the thindg you want!

Comment: and how can I changed the views then? I can't run the runOnUIThread() if it's an independent class.

Comment: why are you using runOnUIThread? what is you requirement for it?

Comment: I read your comment in question is that something you need to change textview contents taht is in caller activity after completing AsyncTask? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions and let me know whether it is useful to you or not

Comment: thank you so much I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I will try this tonight and thanks a lot again and again, I'll get back to you asap!

Answer (score 2):

I believe in most tutorials they pick whatever is easiest to understand/read, not what is actually the best.

With an inner class, you keep your variables of the Activity available, which can be simpler.

In general, you should encapsulate as much as possible, also your AsyncTasks, so you can re-use them from any other point in your code.

Comment: yes this is why i would like to make an independent file for it so i can use it not only for one purpose but for multiple purposes too

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can create `AsyncTask class` in your `MainActivity.java`.

```
public class CategoryListScreen extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new loadcategory().execute();
    }

    class loadcategory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) { }
    } // AsyncTask over
}//main class over
```

Comment: the thing is that i do not want to use it as an inner class. I want to use it as a separate class.