# Error on Swipe Refresh

Tags: java, android

I have two activities-
1. **MainActivity**
2. **Display_Activity**

The main activity has an inner class "check". 
I am trying to access the code written in the inner class "check", by creating its object in the Display_Activity.
**According to me I am able to run the code inside the inner class but the Sharedpreference is getting null from somewhere**
When I swipe to refresh, the application produces a null object exception. I am not able to get where I am supplying the null. I tried to debug but couldn't find it. Please help if you can.

I have provided with both the activities and the logcat.

**Main_Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String value;
String orientation="false";
EditText edtUrl;
String tknnumber;

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
String URL="http://192.168.1.101:8080/DoctorApp/newjsp2.jsp?token=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edtUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtURL);
    orientation="true";
}

public void CallURL(View view) {
    check check1 = new check();
    tknnumber = edtUrl.getText().toString();
    boolean result = isNetworkAvailable();
    if (!result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        check1.Checking_network(tknnumber);
    }
}
public class check{
public void Checking_network(String tkn){
        URL = URL.concat(tkn);
     (new ParseURL()).execute(new String[]{URL});

    }

private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            //Log.d("JSwa", "Connecting to [" + strings[0] + "]");
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
            String token = doc.getElementById("token").ownText();
            String p_name = doc.getElementById("pname").ownText();
            String gender = doc.getElementById("gender").ownText();
            String city = doc.getElementById("city").ownText();
            String date = doc.getElementById("date").ownText();
            String doctor=doc.getElementById("doctor").ownText();
            String time_left=doc.getElementById("time").ownText();

            buffer.append(token+"\n"+p_name+"\n"+gender+"\n"+city+"\n"+date+"\n"+doctor+"\n"+time_left);


        } catch (Exception t) {

            buffer.delete(0,buffer.length());
            buffer.append("Error");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Error")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry! Something went wrong. Make sure you have entered the correct token number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            try{
        callIntent(s);
    }
        catch(Exception e){
            refreshCall(s);}
    }}}
}
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(){

    ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
Context context=this;
void callIntent(String s){
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(context, display_activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("info",s);
    intent.putExtra("token_number",tknnumber);
    startActivity(intent);}

void refreshCall(String s){

    SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("mydata",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("key", s);
    editor.commit();
}}
```

**Display_activity**

```
public class display_activity extends Activity {
TextView token_name,patient,gender,location,date,doctor,token_null,time_left;
String token_received;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
MainActivity.check abc=mainActivity.new check();
String URL="http://192.168.1.101:8080/DoctorApp/newjsp2.jsp?token=";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_activity);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_swipe_refresh_layout);
    token_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tkn);
    patient=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.patient);
    gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    location=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    date=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.date1);
    doctor=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.doctor1);
    token_null=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.token);
    time_left=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_left);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String infor=intent.getStringExtra("info");
    token_received=intent.getStringExtra("token_number");
        breaking(infor);
   mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                refreshContent();
            }});}

public void breaking(String a){
    String delimiter = "\n";
    String[] temp;
    temp = a.split(delimiter);
    try{
        token_name.setText(temp[0]);
        patient.setText(temp[1]);
        gender.setText(temp[2]);
        location.setText(temp[3]);
        date.setText(temp[4]);
        doctor.setText(temp[5]);
        time_left.setText(temp[6]+" mins (approx)");
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

        token_name.setText(a);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void refreshContent(){
    boolean result=isNetworkAvailable();
    if(!result){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {

        abc.Checking_network(token_received);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String information=pref.getString("key","NA");
        breaking(information);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}}


public void Callprevious(View view){
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**logcat On swipe refresh**

```
  06-10 20:00:24.399  12012-12012/com.example.nmn.ajsouptry E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nmn.ajsouptry, PID: 12012
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:169)
        at com.example.nmn.ajsouptry.MainActivity.refreshCall(MainActivity.java:144)
        at com.example.nmn.ajsouptry.MainActivity$check$ParseURL.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:115)
        at com.example.nmn.ajsouptry.MainActivity$check$ParseURL.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:56)
```

**I am a new to this website, please give me time to improve. Kindly see my error and if it seems weird , you can simply ignore it. Thank you.**

Comment: Amazing question you have asked. ` intent = new Intent(?????, A2.class); ` `???` needs context. Put your `MYACTIVITY.this`P.S. MYACTIVITY is the name of your activity

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok. Thanks. @MurtazaKhursheedHussain of course it isn't working that's why posted here.

Comment: You should be using `Activity Context` for `Toast` (`MainActivity.this`). Also, your `context` variable is `null` because you try to initialize it before `onCreate()`.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks for your kind suggestion. I have edited the question again and made it more clear. Please have a look.

Comment: You **never** want to instantiate an Activity with `MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();`. If you need the other class in multiple activities then you should make it a separate class. You don't even need the `check` class. Make the AsyncTask it's own class and create a constructor to accept the url (or any params you may need)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You are totally correct , its not a good idea to instantiate mainActivity. but how will I access getSysytemService() in non activity class? @codeMagic

Comment: Pass the Activity Context to the constructor. Something like `Display_Activity.this`

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409912/should-i-use-asynctask-class-inside-the-mainactivity-extending-activity/15409989#15409989

Comment: That's what i wanted. Thank you so much. And I have so much of confusion in this Context thing. Can you provide me with some link where context is explained with easy examples. I'll be grateful to you. :) @codeMagic

Comment: `Context` is certainly confusing at first and takes time to wrap your head around so don't get frustrated. But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955) helped me in the past along with the [linked article in it](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)

Comment: The linked article seems good. Will read it. Amazing, you solved all my problems for today. Thank you. @codeMagic

Comment: I've reopened now that you've made edits to make it more clear (though you should keep the original code) because this type of question is not a good candidate for the NPE canoncial. The NPE comes from inside the framework instead of simply a variable not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues going on here and most related to [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955) discusses `Context` and [a linked post in the comments](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) explains it very well also.

There are different types of `Context`s being used here when each should just be using the `Activity Context` (i.e. `ActivityName.this`, `this`, or any other way you want to go about getting a hold of the Activity's `Context`.

The underlying problem is that you are trying to reference the `AsyncTask` inner class of one `Activity` from another. You are trying to instantiate the `Activity` with `new MainActivity()` which you should **never** do.

Since the task is needed in multiple activities, simply take it out and make it its own class. You can create a constructor to pass in a url variable or whatever params you need including the Activity `Context`.

Also, you use `Context context = this;` before `onCreate()` runs (you have it outside of a method). This will result in `null` because the `Context` isn't available **before** `onCreate()`.