# Error: SMS API getting Error in Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

I am working on an SMS API and it is working fine on Web but it is getting me error in Android App that SMS cannot be sent. The response generated from that API is:

> http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=bestfolio&password=12345678&sendername=AGPUBS&mobileno=913125603722&message=welcome

Here is my SMS Send Activity

```
    public class SmsSendActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    private String mobile;
    //private String SMS;

    SmsSendActivity(Context context, String mobile, String SMS) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        //  this.SMS = SMS;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            // Construct data
            String username = "username=" + "bestfolio";
            String password = "&password=" + "12345678";
            String sendername = "&sendername=" + "AGPUBS";
            String mobileno = "&mobileno=" + URLEncoder.encode(strings[0], "UTF-8");
            String message = "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode(strings[1], "UTF-8");
            String url = "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?";

            // Send data
            String data = username + password + sendername + mobileno + message;
            Log.e("smsapi", url + data);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url + data).openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
            conn.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("SMS", "" + line);
            }
            rd.close();

            //return stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error is", "" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Here i am calling this class

```
new SmsSendActivity(getApplicationContext(), mobile, thanksMessage).execute(mobile, thanksMessage);
```

Comment: Which exception do you get?

Comment: there isn't any exception; i am getting this response from server:
An error occured while sending Message

Comment: Try setting conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); to GET

Comment: no, it is get method

Comment: It was working fine when i was using it with AppCompatActivity but now i want to send sms directly and now it is getting me error

Comment: You should use URLEncoder.encode function on mobile and SMS variable before adding it to query string.

Comment: i didn't get it. where?

Comment: String message = "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode(SMS,    "UTF-8")

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
getting this exception

Comment: It means you can't do Network operation on the main thread. You need to use AsyncTask or create a new thread to execute this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

private Context context; 

public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {  // can take other params if needed
    this.context = context;
}

// Add your AsyncTask methods and logic
//you can use your context variable in onPostExecute() to manipulate activity UI
```

}
then call it in your MainActivity

```
MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);  //can pass other variables as needed
myTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting NetworkOnMainThreadException then it means you are running network call on main thread which is not allowed in Android. You need to use AsyncTask or another threading mechanism to run the network call on a background thread as shown [here](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial).

Comment: You should use an inner class instead of extending it in your Activity class. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409989/1273550) answer for reference.